# Managed Packaged fields not showing on WSDL

Tags: managed-package, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

Out org has some managed packages installed.

When we try to generate the enterprise wsdl, only some of them appear on the list of packages (so we can set the version). Custom fields on the packages that aren't on the list don't show on the wsdl.

p.s.: We already tryed making SOAP calls to our org and we were able to fill those fields. Also, FLS is set as visible to all profiles.

Is there anything we're missing?

Comment: Is there anything you can use to distinguish the ones that aren't appearing from the ones that are? Are they licensed for the user generating the Enterprise WSDL? Were the problem packages installed with API restrictions?
Interestingly, my dev org has 21 packages installed. Only 9 appear for version selection when generating the Enterprise WSDL.

Comment: Looking closer, only the managed packages are appearing in the list. The rest are unmanaged, and hence don't have a namespace.

Comment: No. The ones that aren't appearing are also Managed. They have no restrictions and all the settings are equal to the one who do appear. (at least the settings I can see).

Comment: I also have access to the dev org of those packages and couldn't find any differences.

Comment: When you say you can make SOAP calls to update the missing fields, how are you doing that. Is that via the Partner API?

Comment: Via SoapUI. Also, we did an upgrade on the packages that didn't appear (via push upgrades) and now they do. I don't know what happened

Comment: If it happens again and you don't have an urgent deadline consider raising it with Salesforce support as a bug. They might be able to isolate the cause.